# Copy/Pasting Formula Values Show as "Loading..."

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a working Google Script macro that copies a Pivot Table/formulas and pastes it as values into another range.

This runs without any issue, but sometimes the pasted values show as "Loading...". My guess is there is some lag or delay between the copy/paste, but how can I ensure the copy/paste will make sure values are loaded before pasting?

I have tried adding in a timed delay function (`Utilities.sleep(1000)`) and a `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` with inconsistent results. These were placed in the line immediately after the paste function. See code below:

```
var sourceRange = sheet.getRange("A:C"); //copy table from  
var destRange = sheet.getRange("D:F"); //copy table to
sourceRange.copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
sourceRange.copyTo(destRange,{contentsOnly:true});
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

Wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue and how can I make sure values are not pasted as "Loading..."?

Comment: Add a [mcve] (the code lines included have variables that we don't know what values they have).

Comment: Works okay for me once you define the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange('A1').getDataRegion(); 
  var destRange = sheet.getRange('D1'); 
  sourceRange.copyTo(destRange,{contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Cooper. Just wondering - what does the 'getDataRegion' function add? To note, my sourceRange is a dynamic PivotTable with changing # of rows but static columns. The code runs without any problems but my main issue is that it copy/pastes over the "Loading..."  text sometimes if the data set is large or internet connection is slow.

Comment: Why do you perform both of these commands? `sourceRange.copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
sourceRange.copyTo(destRange,{contentsOnly:true});` You read about getDataRegion() [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDataRegion())

Comment: I need to copy/paste both as format and as values only. This issue still persists even if I have only one copyTO